# Change DHCP on server 2k3

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2003, dhcp-server

Ok I am trying to mess with our dhcp settings on our domain server because at this point we kinda have competing dhcp servers between the router and the server. (Long predates me and I have finally got tired of it.)

The server will give out ip address but no DNS or Default Gateway addresses. Where do I need to set these? I see that both scope options and server options seem to talk about doing this. Am I in the right place or do I need to go elsewhere?

Comment: Hmmm...Windows Server 2003 is nearly EOL, I hope that you are quickly migrating off this to something that will be support.

Comment: Doubt it. We still have windows 95 in active use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are duplicate options, applied at different levels.

'Server options' apply to all defined DHCP scopes on the server. 'Scope options' apply to only that specific DHCP scope (you can have more than one scope defined in the DHCP server).

Comment: Seeing as I only have one scope it should not matter at what level I apply it then?

Comment: It's up to you. Personally I apply them at each scope, since often  each scope will have different options. Helps prevent surprise settings from the server-level being distributed to a scope you add later on.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. It seems to be working. I'll find out if it does not soon when people come and complain.

Comment: If you're also using the server as your clients' DNS (which you should be), you should next look into having DHCP auto-update DNS. It's handy. :)

Comment: It is the only server we have. It has DNS setup but I don't know past that how it is setup. In the dhcp scope options I added the servers own address as the first dns address with google's addresses as the second and third. I know from past experience that the server needs to be the first or the computers have issues with finding the domain.